# how to show DialogFragment safely?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I wrote below code showing dialog by Button click

```
@OnClick(R.id.button)
public void buttonClicked(View v) {
  DialogFragment dialog = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
  dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG);
}
```

It works well, but when I click button many times, and very quickly, 
below Exception occurred and crash app.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: MyDialogFragment
```

I try below code, but same Exception occurred.

```
@OnClick(R.id.button)
public void buttonClicked(View v) {
  DialogFragment dialog = 
    (DialogFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);
  if (dialog != null && dialog.isAdded()) {
    return;
  }
  dialog = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
  dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG);
}

@OnClick(R.id.button)
public void buttonClicked(View v) {
  DialogFragment dialog = 
    (DialogFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);
  if (dialog != null && dialog.isAdded()) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(dialog).commit();
    return;
  }
  dialog = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
  dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG);
}
```

How can I deal with this Exception ?

Comment: this problem may occurs in case of opening DialogFragment from other fragment.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you.

Have a boolean filled called lock.

```
private boolean locked;
```

When you want to create and show dialog check that field:

```
if(!locked) {
    locked = true;
    //create and show fragment
}
```

Toggle locked to false when you dismiss your dialog.

Comment: thanks, it may one solution. but I want to avoid redundant field if possible.